# How do i use SF Symbol icons on macOS

Tags: cocoa, macos-catalina, sf-symbols

I want to add glyhps from the MacOS Catalina icon font into my NSString.

I use the SF Symbols app and the few icons which show a unicode codepoint  are easy to embed like normal characters but how do i use the ones where no codepoint is shown (the overwhelming majority).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i found the website http://mathew-kurian.github.io/CharacterMap

Just upload your SF Symbol font from /Library/Fonts  and then the character name contains the unicode hex codepoint.